# Calling Oracle stored procedure from Java

Tags: java, oracle

I'm calling an Oracle stored function using `JDBC` thin driver.
Following is the code.

```
class testSP 
{ 
  public static void main (String args []) 
                     throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException 
  { 
      String driver_class = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"; 
      String connect_string = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxx.xx.xx.xx:1521:xxxx"; 

      Connection conn; 

      Class.forName(driver_class); 
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connect_string, "xxxx", "xxxx"); 

      // OracleCallableStatement ocs = 
      //    (OracleCallableStatement)conn.prepareCall(
      //        "{? = call acpks_stmt_gen.fn_stmt_gen(?,?,?,?,?,?)}");
      CallableStatement ocs = 
         conn.prepareCall(
            "{? = call acpks_stmt_gen.fn_stmt_gen(?,?,?,?,?,?)}");

      ocs.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.ARRAY);

      ocs.setString(2, "144000014");
      ocs.setString(3, "RET");
      ocs.setString(4, "N");
      ocs.setString(5, "3");
      ocs.setNull(6, java.sql.Types.DATE) ;
      ocs.setNull(7, java.sql.Types.DATE);



      ocs.executeUpdate(); 

     // java.sql.ResultSet rs2 = (java.sql.ResultSet) ocs.getResultSet();

  }

}
```

When I call this I get an exception as following

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: ORA-03115: unsupported network datatype or representation
```

I'm using the thin driver `ojdbc6.jar` provided by Oracle.
and I'm using this in my class path.

Thanks.

Comment: which version of oracle you are using?

Comment: What does `fn_stmt_gen` return? Might just be a clash of types, there are various `OracleTypes` that might be more appropriate. Possibly better to revert to the `OracleCallableStatement` too.

Comment: I tried OracleCallableStmt. Also the fn_stmt_gen returns a PL/SQL user definied collection type.

Comment: If OracleTypes.ARRAY and OracleTypes.PLSQL_INDEX_TABLE don't work, I'd try returning it as a result set instead; maybe have a query that does something like `select * from table(cast acpks_stmt_gen.fn_stmt_gen(?,?,?,?,?,?) as <your type>)`? Might be helpful to know more about the function.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
  ocs.setString(6, "") ;
  ocs.setString(7, "");
```

instead of

```
  ocs.setNull(6, java.sql.Types.DATE);
  ocs.setNull(7, java.sql.Types.DATE);
```

making use of the fact that in Oracle, the empty string is the same as NULL.

In my current project, I've encountered similar problems with NULLs that could be solved that way. (Yes, that's fugly)